# HttpResponseRedirect with reverse not passing parameters

Tags: python, django

In one definition of my view I am doing this

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'),{"fail":"true"})
```

then the destination receiving definition in a view does this

```
def Validate(request):
    rslt = request.GET.get("fail", "False")  #--->fail is always false
    ....
    ....
```

In the above the variable fail is always `false` . Any suggestions on why I am always getting a false. Why is my new parameter not being passed ?

Comment: Why is this marked as close ? Am I missing any detail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it because you are asking for `fail` from `GET` but you are not passing anything in GET.

you need:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?fail=%s' % (reverse('home'), True))
```

then you can catch it like:

```
request.GET.get("fail", False)
```

dont misuse Booleans! ;)

Comment: wait I am confused. Am I not passing {"fail":"true"} in my first statement ? I was under the impression that passing parameters like `home?key=Val` is same as redirect HttpResponseRedirect("home",{"key":"val"}) ?

Comment: If 'fail' is not in get, this will be a bool, otherwise a string. You should add some `cast/eval` logic

Comment: @Rajeshwar not as GET. It is even wrong for positional arguments. It should be `reverse('home', kwargs={"fail": True})`

Comment: @Rajeshwar I have never seen anything like `HttpResponseRedirect("home",{"key":"val"})` before

Comment: @doniyor if I go with `reverse('home', kwargs={"fail": True})` with  `url(r'home' ,'main.views.myfunct' , name="home")` defined in my `urls.py`. It does not hit my definition

Comment: @Rajeshwar because your urlconf is wrong: it should be `url(r'^home/$', 'main.views.myfunct', name='home')`. and you cannot pass `kwargs` because you didnot define them in your urlconf. --> use GET, the version in my answer above

Answer (score 1):

The `args` and `kwargs` passed to the `HttpResponseRedirect` constructor

```
def __init__(self, redirect_to, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

are not being used to construct a `QueryDict` (get or post). You are initialising a response here, not a request. As doniyor has already stated you basically have to append the querystring manually to the path returned by `reverse()`:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('{to}?{query}'.format(
    to=reverse('home'),
    query=urllib.urlencode({"fail":"true"})
))
```

This has nothing to do with django, but general http redirection. You can only redirect a request to a location (to which you can add a query string), but you cannot tamper with the request itself, like adding POST-data or setting headers.

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination. That clears up a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need give a second parameter at reverse function... as de arguments... this works well for me!!!

```
    return reverse('home', args='true')
```